# How memory is allocated to object in java

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I have POJO class containing 300 variable in it. I want to hold list of these POJO classes. Out of these 300 fields 150 will always be NULL, because of no use. 
Would you please let me know will JVM allocate memory to null fields? Will it be problematic for heap memory?

Comment: This question sounds a bit nonsense

Comment: total space required per object is as per the first answer (total * 4 bytes for 32 bit or total * 8 bytes for 64 bit systems). but 300 is a lot of variables from a maintainability point of view. i would recommend grouping them into separate objects eg. all address fields would go into an Address object which id referenced via an address member:  private Address address;  this in itself can be null if no address is defined.

Answer (score 1):

In Java even when a field is null, it still occupies 4 bytes on 32-bit systems or 8 bytes on 64-bit systems to keep the null reference. So, in this case, the object will use 150*4 (150*8 for 64-bit) extra bytes just to keep the unused fields. However, that is not a big deal until you do not allocate too many instances at the same time.